# how can i block a user using a .json file in discord py rewrite?

Tags: json, discord.py

hello i got an issue with my json file. i wanted to load in my json file to delete user messages of users, who are written down in this file (the ids). to check if the client gets it i said the console to print it if the json file was loaded and a second time it should print DONE if it works.

here is my code.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  with open('./bot_config/blocked_users.json', 'r') as json_file:
       json_dict = json.load(json_file)
       print(message.author.id)
  if message.author.id in json_dict:
       await message.delete()
       await message.author.send('Du darfst keine Nachrichten verschicken, da du blockiert wurdest! :smile:')
       print('DONE')
       return
```

i know that the issue is on the line

```
if message.author.id in json_dict:
```

and i want to know how to replace it because i have no idea. i also tried

```
if message.author.id in json_file:
```

but nothing happens.

edit: here is my json file.

```
{
    "blockedUser": [
        805047615128469534
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your json file?

Comment: yes here is the json file. 

`{
    "blockedUser": [
        805047615128469534
    ]
}`

the client can show the user id, but not the DONE at the end. so as i said, i need to do something different with the if funcion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.load` simply converts the entire file into a dictionary or list, depending on your json. So you're json would be converted to a dictionary with a single key `blockedUser`. Hence, we have if the user is in the value of that key.

```py
if message.author.id in json_dict['blockedUser']:
   #user is blocked
```